# Search interface for Android application

Tags: android

I have currently implemented the search interface in Android using the dialog box. However, I need to change this and place the search edit elsewhere in the app.  By default the search dialog is at the very top of the application, and it has to move.  Now I see in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html it says there is a Widget option with Android 3.0+ however, I still need to support Android 2.1, 2.2

So I would like to use the Android search interface with its advantages like voice search etc, but how can I put the search edit box somewhere other than the very top, and still be compliant for Android 2.1, 2.2?